# JAVA could not find or load main class when I add external library

Tags: java, external

There are some encoding character in my code so I compile the code as follow:

```
javac -cp cayenne-2.0.4.jar Twokenize.java
```

It's ok. But when I run the program, it return an error:

```
java -cp cayenne-2.0.4.jar Twokenize test.txt
```

Here is an error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Twokenize
```

But when I just run:

```
java Twokenize test.txt
```

The program (main method) still runs smoothly util it meets the code that require external library.
Please help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: you forgot to add current folder to the classpath. And java tries to find Tokenize class in cayenne jar file.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov You right. Thank you. I just wonder how do you know that.

Comment: When you launch java with `-cp` parameter you are specifying classpath for **all classes**. In case you have specified only one jar file, java decides to find Tokenize class into this jar file. And cannot find it and throws the exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

when you use `-cp` it looses current directory from classpath so you need to specify explicitly

Use

```
java -cp .:cayenne-2.0.4.jar Twokenize test.txt
```

Comment: Thank you indeed, It works. Could you recommend any good document related to practicing JAVA. I really appreciate it.

Comment: You are welcome :) (also to accept it as answer since it answers it), good document for practice is too vague

Comment: @HoaVu I recommend Bruce Eckel "Thinking in Java" and Joshua Bloch's book "Effective Java".

Comment: Thank you @RafaelOsipov. I really appriciate it.